# Converting HTACCESS rewrite rules to Nginx

Tags: nginx, webserver

I have the following rewrite rule in a .htaccess file. How can I get this to work in Nginx?

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/\.]+)/?$ profile.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Tried this and it didn't work:

```
rewrite profile.php?id=$1 ^profile/([0-9]+)/?$ break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your [Nginx rewrite](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) parameters are reversed.

Assuming that your `.htaccess` file is located in the document root, try:

```
rewrite ^/profile/([0-9]+)/?$ /profile.php?id=$1 last;
```

- All Nginx URLs begin with a leading `/`, so both the regex and the replacement should begin with `^/` and `/` respectively.
- The replacement is a PHP script, so the `last` flag should be used to make Nginx search for the appropriate `location` block to process PHP scripts.
- If the `.htaccess` file is in a subdirectory, it will apply to URLs that are prefixed with that subdirectory, so both the regex and the replacement should be prefixed with that subdirectory.

Comment: Thank you, where should the rewrite be within the server { } tag?

Comment: Generally it doesn't matter. The top of [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) describes the processing order for directives in the rewrite module. Only the order of `break`, `if`, `rewrite`, `return` and `set` statements is significant.